# Acumatica will only update 3 out of 4 Usr Customized Fields in CRQUOTE

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have four Custom fields in an Extension DAC. These are an extension of CRQuote:

```
public class CRQuoteExt : PXCacheExtension<CRQuote>
```

During the Update Row Event, I go through the products listed on the quote, and calculate the totals for the discount, and the margins, and put these values in my Customized extension fields.

This works fine... For three out of four of them. But the fourth will not use the calculated values. Instead it fills in the values that it finds in the database.

All four fields are identical in their definition.

Here is the DAC Code of two of the fields -- the first one works. The second does not.

```
    #region UsrASGMarginPercent
    [PXDBDecimal]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Margin %", Enabled = false)]
    public virtual decimal? UsrASGMarginPercent { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrASGMarginPercent : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<usrASGMarginPercent> { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrASGDiscTotal
    [PXDBDecimal]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Discount Total", Enabled = false)]
    public virtual decimal? UsrASGDiscTotal { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrASGDiscTotal : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<usrASGDiscTotal> { }
    #endregion
```

The second one, UsrASGDiscTotal, will not accept the calculated value. Even though I literally copied and pasted the code from the UsrASGMarginPercent field and just changed the names. So, they are syntactically the same.

Here is the section of code that sets the customized fields on Update:

```
      public void CRQuoteUpdateRow(CRQuote quote)
    {
      decimal? QuoteTotalDiscount = 0;
      CRQuoteExt quoteExt = quote.GetExtension<CRQuoteExt>();
      quoteExt.UsrASGMarginCury = CRQuoteMarginCury(quote);
      quoteExt.UsrASGMarginPercent = CRQuoteMarginPercent(quote);
      quoteExt.UsrASGQuoteCostField = CRQuoteCostCalc(quote, out QuoteTotalDiscount);
      quoteExt.UsrASGDiscTotal = QuoteTotalDiscount;
      int stp = 0;
      ...
```

I put a breakpoint at the "int stp = 0;" line and watch it at runtime. The value is getting calculated fine. And all of the calculations in the other fields set the values as expected:

[image: VS Screenshot]

But, when it comes to the screen, the value is not the calculated amount (which would be 165.11, but rather 99.99 -- which is what is in the database field.)

As you can see in this screenshot:

[image: Sales Quote]

The value is coming from the database -- but just for this field"

[image: SQL Server Query]

I even checked the ASP values, but they are all the same, as well:

[image: ASPX]

What's going on here?

Comment: where did the 99.99 come from ? can you manually run a script to change it to something else ?

Comment: @Rick  As I pointed out, the 99.99 came from the database. I put it in there by running an SQL script, so, yes, I can change it via a script.

Answer (score 0):

With some assistance from @Yuriy Zaletskyy, I have a workaround to this issue.

This works. I do not know why. Just that it does:

```
decimal? QuoteTotalDiscount = 0;
CRQuoteExt quoteExt = quote.GetExtension<CRQuoteExt>();
quoteExt.UsrASGMarginCury = CRQuoteMarginCury(quote);
quoteExt.UsrASGMarginPercent = CRQuoteMarginPercent(quote);
quoteExt.UsrASGQuoteCostField = CRQuoteCostCalc(quote, out QuoteTotalDiscount);
/***************************************************************/
/* The Tricky Part:                                            */
/***************************************************************/                
Base.Quote.Cache.SetValue<CRQuoteExt.usrASGDiscTotal>(quote, QuoteTotalDiscount);
```